# Diferença entre Sumarização e Paráfrase?

Tags: significado

Qual a diferença entre essas duas formas de reescrever um texto? Como um paráfase e uma sumarização devem ser estruturadas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O contexto vai determinar um pouco do significado, mas basicamente:

- **Sumarização** é construir um resumo, produzir um texto que condense o sentido do texto original, focando nos pontos principais.
- **Paráfrase** é dizer a mesma coisa com outras palavras (geralmente as suas próprias palavras).

Os termos podem ainda ter alguma sobreposição: ao fazer uma paráfrase, você pode estar também resumindo o texto (ao não abordar todos os temas que ele aborda), e ao resumir você está apresentando as ideias dele de uma outra forma.

Comment: A paráfrase não resume o texto. Pelo contrário, expande-o, com o objetivo de apresentar as ideias do texto original de forma mais fácil de compreender.

Comment: Exatamente, @Jacinto.

Comment: Então tira a última frase da tua resposta. _(...) ao fazer uma paráfrase, você pode estar também resumindo_ no mínimo confunde.

Comment: Mas eu não acho errado. Não é condição que a paráfrase trate de absolutamente todas as ideias do texto original. Entendo que como escrevi possa parecer confuso, vou pensar em alguma edição que melhore.

Comment: Veja se acha melhor assim, @Jacinto.

Comment: Eu não sou especialista em paráfrases, mas parece-me que na tua explicação falta o aspeto essencial de a paráfrase expandir o texto original. Vou pôr a definição do DACL numa resposta, e o Lucas fica com duas respostas

Answer (score 1):

A explicação de bfaravetto de sumarização está ótima.

Paráfrase -- reproduzo aqui verbatim a definição do Dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa, que não está disponível online:

> 1. Enunciado mais extenso que contém a mesma informação que uma palavra ou outro enunciado mais conciso.
> 2. Desenvolvimento explicativo de um texto que se limita a reproduzir, por outras palavras e de forma acrítica, aquele texto.

E talvez ajude também a definição de **parafrasear**:

> Reproduzir um enunciado recorrendo a uma expressão mais longa, mais extensa, menos concisa mas com significado equivalente, geralmente para explicar, para tornar mais claro; expressar por paráfrase.

Portanto paráfrase é essencialmente o oposto de sumário.

Comment: Eu acho que em Português de Portugal não usamos essa palavra e sim *sumariar*. Estou certo?

Comment: Acho que _sumariar_ é mais usado que _sumarizar_, mas não tenho a certeza. _Sumariação/sumarização_ é tão raro, que não faço a mínima ideia. Mesmo _sumariar/sumarizar_ é pouco usado; que se usa mais é _resumir_. Talvez entre o pessoal de Letras seja diferente.

Comment: É bastante usado nas escolas, embora seja usado como *fazer o sumário*.

Comment: Exatamente. Mas eu na escola não _sumariava_, _escrevia o sumário!_